# How to bring back user agent stylesheet for specific elements only?

Tags: css, compass-sass, compass

I use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) in my web development. It has a `reset` component:

> @import "compass/reset";

This component resets user agent stylesheet and any header tag `<h1>Hello, World</h1>` renders text just like a plain `<span>`. Here is how Compass resets:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

However, I would like to enable user agent stylesheets for headers `h(1-5)` only. Does current web/browser standards/functions has such an option?

Comment: Why not just make a 2:nd version of the component and take the `h(1-5)` out?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the whole purpose of the CSS reset; it flattens out elements so all styles applied after the reset will look similar across browsers and reduce the amount of CSS you need to write to give the same appearance.

Probably a CSS reset is not what you're after and you'll probably need a [CSS normalize](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/).

Hopefully someone developed a Compass plugin for normalize.css, [which you can find here](https://github.com/ksmandersen/compass-normalize) with detailed installation instructions.

After the gem installation and requiring the library on your `config.rb` file you can import individual parts of the normalize.css

So if you want to normalize everything apart from `<H1>` - `<H6>` tags you can import everything keeping out `@import 'normalize/typography';` from your SASS/SCSS file.

```
@import 'normalize/html5';
@import 'normalize/base';
@import 'normalize/links';
@import 'normalize/embeds';
@import 'normalize/groups';
@import 'normalize/forms';
@import 'normalize/tables';
```

That would be the most reusable and cleaner way to do it. However, if you strictly need a reset.css, avoiding all other browser defaults all I can suggest to you is to create your own reset.css in a separate file, taking out the tags you don't want to be resetted and then importing it on your main SASS/SCSS file.